# How I can resize while uploading an image

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I need to resize an image while uploading. WHat I need to add to do that?

html file:

```
> <form action="news.php?action=save" method="post"
> enctype="multipart/form-data" id="post" name="post" onsubmit="return
> chkFormular();"><ul>
>       <li>Newspic frontpage<br /><br />
>             <input name="banner" type="file" /> (width must be equal to: 307px)<br /><br />
>       </li>
>       </ul></form>
```

news.php:

```
$banner = $_FILES['banner'];
$id=$newsID;

    $filepath = "images/news_pics/";
if ($banner['name'] != "") {
    move_uploaded_file($banner['tmp_name'], $filepath.$banner['name']);
    @chmod($filepath.$banner['name'], 0755);
    $file_ext=strtolower(substr($banner['name'], strrpos($banner['name'], ".")));
    $file=$id.$file_ext;
    if(file_exists($filepath.$file)) @unlink($filepath.$file);
    rename($filepath.$banner['name'], $filepath.$file);
    safe_query("UPDATE ".PREFIX."news SET banner='$file' WHERE newsID = '".$newsID."'");

}
```

I want to resize pics to a width of 307px and height could be automatic. And with that resize the filesize as well.

Of course I already did the resize thing in the  but that's not what I searching for.

Comment: what *exactly* is the problem?

Comment: those are my files. I have the uploading stuff working great, but I want to make something to resize the image while uploading for a width of 307px and an automatic height. Is that possible?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with MySQL or CSS. You may wish to investigate the Gmagick extension to php. http://www.php.net/manual/en/gmagick.examples.php

Answer (score -1):

http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-and-resize-with-jquery-and-php

See the functions:resizeImage() and cropImage()

Set the width and height of img in html accordingly.